# show multiple choice questions with answers to user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a problem about displaying multiple choice questions to user. i have the following tables:

**multiple_choice_questions** (quiz_id, question,c_answer) 
this table have the questions with the right answers

**multiple_choice_answers** (answer_id, quiz_id,answer)
this table have the answers with the foreign key quiz_id

**multiple_choice_info** (info_id,quiz_id,name,class, lesson, subject, notes,date)
here are basic informations for each quiz which actually helps in choosing the appropriate quiz from the user. e.g. if a user puts as lesson mathematics it show the tests with "lesson" mathematics

i want to display for example 10 random questions with their answers. note that each questions has plurality of different answers. e.g. question 1 have 3 different answers. question 2, 5 different answers.

i made an effort to catch the data related with the quiz_id but this method is wrong. im new in php, mysql.

```
<?php
include('../connect_db.php');

$sql = "select * from multiple_choice_questions
inner join multiple_choice_answers on (multiple_choice_questions.quiz_id =      multiple_choice_answers.quiz_id)
inner join multiple_choice_info on (multiple_choice_questions.quiz_id = multiple_choice_info.quiz_id)";
$myData3 = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData3)) {
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$row['question'].'" name="q'.$row['quiz_id'].'"/><br>';
echo '<input type="radio" value="'.$row['answer'].'" name="q'.$row['answer'].'"/>"'.$row['answer'].'"';

}
?>
```

Comment: Why have you got `quiz_id` on your questionaire table? Isn't `quiz_id` a question ID? In that case it would be 1:1 relationship of question:questionaire.

Comment: to enable a teacher to puts as many answers he wants

Comment: So you are duplicating the questionnaire row for every question that is applied to it? The db structure doesn't seem right. It would be better with an info_id in the question table, so that questions can relate to a questionnaire, and you can have many questions to one questionnaire.

Answer (score 0):

Format your query in the below way. This will give you 10 rows randomly.

```
$sql = "select A.question,B.answer,A.quizid from multiple_choice_questions AS A
inner join multiple_choice_answers AS B on (A.quiz_id = B.quiz_id)
inner join multiple_choice_info AS C on (C.quiz_id = A.quiz_id) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
$myData3 = mysql_query($sql);
```

Can you try the below script.

```
    $sql = "select A.question,B.answer,A.quizid from multiple_choice_questions AS A
inner join multiple_choice_answers AS B on (A.quiz_id = B.quiz_id)
inner join multiple_choice_info AS C on (C.quiz_id = A.quiz_id) 
ORDER BY A.quizid,RAND()";
$myData3 = mysql_query($sql);

    $lastQues = 0;
$totalQues = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData3)) {

    if($totalQues == 10)break;



    if($lastQues != $row['quiz_id'])
    {
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$row['question'].'" name="q'.$row['quiz_id'].'"/><br>';
        $totalQues++;
    }
    echo '<input type="radio" value="'.$row['answer'].'" name="q'.$row['answer'].'"/>"'.$row['answer'].'"';

    $lastQues = $row['quiz_id'];

}
```

Comment: this shows me 10 answers with 10 questions.. is not what i need. i need each question to have its answer from below. e.g. question 1: how are you? answer 1: im fine, answer 2 .. , answer 3 etc

Comment: this is good but each question has 3 answers in this example. in my case each question has different number of answers. e.g. question 1: 3 different answers. question 2: 5 different answers. the number of answers depend on multiple_choice_answers table. one other problem is that i can select all radio buttons, not only one.

Comment: Got that. I have changed the logic. Let me know. Also, when you format the question, you should give all your requirements so that you get the perfect answer at the first time.